# PHP: Why mail() won´t send Bcc when there are several recipients?

Tags: php, email

I´m testing mail() capabilities, and I have this form field named "mailList" which is a textarea witha  couple of mails separated by commas.

**So here´s my input form:** `<textarea name="listadoMails"></textarea>`

**And I´m trying this:**

```
$listadoMails = $_POST["listadoMails"];

$para   = 'myOwnMail@gmail.com';
$asunto = $_POST['subject'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$headers = 'From: myOwnMail@mysite.com';
$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$listadoMails. "\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


if($_POST['listadoMails']) {
    //mando mail a los usuarios
    $envioUsuarios = mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers);
    }

if($envioUsuarios) { // I then echo a message that the email was successfully sent.
    echo 'Se envió mensaje a '. $listadoMails;  
}
```

Te message appears as successfully sent. The mail is just sent to my own email, and the **From** line in that only email sent is **"Nobody "**

So I have two issues really:

**BBC emails are not sent, and the From address won´t work either!**

Comment: use an SMTP mailer like `PHPMailer`see here http://phpmailer.worxware.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found that it was a silly mistake:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

should have been

```
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

I didn´t add that line to the first one and everything broke.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you forgot to use "\r\n" at the end of from header.

---

Hope it help